# Vim OS-based config

Tags: vim, fonts

For a reason I can't figure out, the Monaco font doesn't render the same at all on Mac and Linux... It's really beautiful on my Macbook but not on Linux where I use Inconsolata.

I've got a dotfiles git repository to have my config on all my computers.

How do I automatically set in my `.gvimrc` the font to `Monaco` when on Mac and `Inconsolata` elsewhere ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if has("mac")
   set guifont="Monaco"
else
   set guifont="Inconsolata"
endif
```

check also the documentation about the [feature-list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#feature-list).